# From a differrent HTML website to a different Wordpress website redirection using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a website in HTML and I have this link http://html-website.com/CA_NutritionIncentiveProgram.htm which I would like to redirect to https://wordpress-website.com/ca_nutritionincentiveprogram

I have this on my htaccess file but its not working

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# Redirect non WordPress pages to corresponding post
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/CA_NutritionIncentiveProgram/.htm$ https://wordpress-website.com/ca_nutritionincentiveprogram [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

When I load this HTML site http://html-website.com/CA_NutritionIncentiveProgram.htm it redirects me to the wordpress site but with the .htm included (https://wordpress-website.com/ca_nutritionincentiveprogram.htm)

Here is what I have recently (source: RavinderSingh13)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^html-website.com$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.html-website.com$
    RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.wordpress-website.com.com/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(ca_nutritionincentiveprogram)/?$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
    RewriteRule ^(.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}.html [NE,L]
</IfModule>
```

Any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your orignal rule is fine and should work if used in `server.config` context. If you want to marke it work in `htaccess` then you need to remove the leading slash because `RewriteRule` directive uses a relative path (starting without /)  in `htaccess` .

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# Redirect non WordPress pages to corresponding post
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^CA_NutritionIncentiveProgram\.htm$ https://theappliancejudge.co.uk/ca_nutritionincentiveprogram [R=301,L,NC]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: @Amit Verma thank you so much, this works well

Comment: @Amit Verma Now I have this problem with PDF's, how can I redirect it to the new wordpress site for example http://html-website.com/F2F_Strategic_Plan.pdf to https://wordpress-website.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/F2F_Strategic_Plan.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following, based on your shown samples only. Please make sure you clear cache of your browser before testing your URLs. Also in you need not to put `R=301` else it will rewrite that URL in browser to new one(which we obviously don't want to show users).

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*ca_nutritionincentiveprogram)/?$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}/%1.html [NE,L]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help but its still not working, please see My edited question, I put there what I have and added your code

Comment: @FrancisAlvinTan, could you please ping me sample url which you are hitting? btw these rules check if `ca_nutritionincentiveprogram.html` is present in your path or not if its present then only it will redirect request in backend to it.

Comment: is there a message system here in Stackoverflow?

Comment: @FrancisAlvinTan, you need not to tell me exact url just sample like `http://localhost:80/bla_bla_bla_test` like that will be ok.

Comment: @FrancisAlvinTan, could you please check my edited solution once, I made a slight change into it, kindly do let me know how it goes, thank you.

Comment: Thank you for the help, much appreciated